# evento a JTextArea

Tags: java

Hola que tal podrían ayudarme, soy nuevo en el tema de eventos en java.

tengo esta clase, la cual simplemente crea un formulario con 2 objetos JTextArea.

Deseo saber como imprimir un saludo en consola al alternar la posicion del cursor entre los 2 objetos JTextArea; es decir si por ejemplo escribo algo en ct y luego hago click sobre ct2 que imprima en consola "hola"

```
package javaapplication1;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class JavaApplication1 extends JFrame
{
    private JTextArea ct;
    private JTextArea ct2;

    public JavaApplication1()
    {

        setLayout (null);
        ct = new JTextArea();
        ct.setSize(75,30);    
        ct.setLocation(0, 0);
        add(ct);

        ct2 = new JTextArea();
        ct2.setSize(75,30);    
        ct2.setLocation(100, 0);
        add(ct2);

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       JavaApplication1 v1 = new JavaApplication1();
       v1.setVisible(true);
       v1.setSize(200, 200);

    }



}
```

Comment: Con [`java.awt.event.FocusListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html). Más información en [How to Write a Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) en [*The Java™ Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
nombreDelTextArea.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Creo recordar que era algo así, mira a ver si te vale.